# Customer Invitation in magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.4

Can we find email-id of them which are invited by specific customer of Magento say "xyz@abc.com"?

I know We can fetch the record for those who have accepted the invitation by table **rewardpoints_referral**,

My question is here Can we get the records which are not accepted yet and if yes, then by which table?

Thanks!

Comment: please rephrase your question and it's useful to add your exact magento version and if you are using an extension to manage invites then its good to mention that

Comment: Is this Enterprise version or CE?

Comment: am using Magento ver. 1.4.0.1 CE

Comment: @Shine, there must be an extension.  The table `rewardpoints_referral` is not created by Magento.

Comment: rewarpoints_referral is indeed part of J2T's Points and Reward module.

Comment: @vrnet yes, you right here..am using the same

Answer (score 0):

If you are using J2T's Points and Reward module (1)

This snippet will list all emails of referrals that have not signed up as customer yet.
I've tested it on a 28000 customer base and it is very fast.

```
/* Retrieve all referrals emails */
$allReferrals = Mage::getModel('rewardpoints/referral')->getCollection();
foreach($allReferrals as $referral) {
    $allReferralsEmails[] = $referral->getRewardpointsReferralEmail();
}

/* Retrieve all signed-up customers that are referrals */
$allReferralsCustomers = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')->addFieldToFilter('email', array('in'=>$allReferralsEmails));
foreach($allReferralsCustomers as $allReferralsCustomer) {
    $allReferralsCustomerData = $allReferralsCustomer->getData();
    $allReferralsCustomersEmails[] = $allReferralsCustomerData['email'];
}

/* Extract referrals that are not signed-up customers */
$notSignedUpReferralsEmails = array_diff($allReferralsEmails, $allReferralsCustomersEmails);
print_r($notSignedUpReferralsEmails);
```

(1) the rewardpoints_referral table should have this structure :

```
rewardpoints_referral_id    int(11)     UNSIGNED    No      auto_increment                          
rewardpoints_referral_parent_id int(11)     UNSIGNED    No                                  
rewardpoints_referral_child_id  int(11)     UNSIGNED    Yes NULL                                
rewardpoints_referral_email varchar(255)    utf8_general_ci     No                                  
rewardpoints_referral_name  varchar(255)    utf8_general_ci     Yes NULL                                
rewardpoints_referral_status    tinyint(1)          Yes 0
```

Comment: @vrnrt..thanks for youe response! rewardpoints_referral table have the same structure, but the rewardpoints_referral_status shows the status that if the invited person has purchased or not, its not showing here that if he has signed up or not.

Comment: @Shine - I have updated my answer in order to list all emails of referrals that have not signed up as customer.